# Koin Injection module not initializing Room module fast enough?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, koin

I'm creating an app about weather and I want to add some offline caching. The problem is that whenever I add the database in a repository's constructor inside a module in my MainActivity I get an error as if the Database was not created yet but if I remove the Dao from constructor the app works fine.

I add the database module in my Application which works with no issues :

```
        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@WeatherApplication)
            modules(
                PersistenceModule,
                ApiModule
            )
        }
```

The module itself is this :

```
val PersistenceModule = module {
    single {
        Room.databaseBuilder(
            androidApplication(),
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            "appDatabase",
        ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    }

    single { get<AppDatabase>().cityDao }
}
```

In the main and only activity of the app I initialize a module that contains a repository that has in its constructor the Dao I want to use:

MainActivity :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        loadKoinModules(cityModule)
    }
```

Module of MainActivity :

```
val cityModule = module {

    single<ICityRepo> { CityRepoImpl(get(), get()) }

    single { TestingViewModel(get(), get()) }

    single { GetForecastUseCase(get()) }
}
```

And Repository I'm talking about :

```
class CityRepoImpl(
    private val api: OpenWeatherApi,
    private val cityDao: CityDao,
) : ICityRepo {
```

When I do that I get

```
Instance creation error : could not create instance for [Singleton:'com.example.justweather.data.persistence.AppDatabase']: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.justweather.data.persistence.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
```

What's weird and 100% my fault is that if I move the Dao from the constructor inside the repository's Implementation class, it becomes like this and works :

```
class CityRepoImpl(
    private val api: OpenWeatherApi
) : ICityRepo, KoinComponent {
    private val cityDao: CityDao by inject()
```

It's obvious I am missing something if the Dao is injected in the constructor. What is it though?

Comment: Could you share somewhere your code?

Comment: @deadfish Sure! Here's the [link](https://github.com/KaradimoulasG/JustWeather) to my github repo that contains everything. Basically, if you are to insert the Dao in the repository's constructor, you'll get this error. Btw, feel free to judge my code and provide any kind of feedback to improve the quality of it